# onItemClick giving wrong position in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, position, adapter, onitemclick

I found this question:
[GridView with a baseAdapter: onItemClick giving wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238855/gridview-with-a-baseadapter-onitemclick-giving-wrong-position)

I have the same problem! Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Comment: I solved it, check link for answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GridView with a baseAdapter: onItemClick giving wrong position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238855/gridview-with-a-baseadapter-onitemclick-giving-wrong-position)